# Macro definitions for headers, where to put them?

Tags: c, macros, header, autotools, build-system

***When defining macros that headers rely on, such as `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS`, `FUSE_USE_VERSION`, `_GNU_SOURCE` among others, where is the best place to put them?***

Some possibilities I've considered include

1. At the top of the any source files that rely on definitions exposed by headers included in that file
2. Immediately before the include for the relevant header(s)
3. Define at the `CPPFLAGS` level via the compiler? (such as `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64`) for the:

   1. Entire source repo
   2. The whole project
   3. Just the sources that require it
4. In project headers, which should also include those relevant headers to which the macros apply
5. Some other place I haven't thought of, but is infinitely superior

A note: Justification by applicability to make, autotools, and other build systems is a factor in my decision.

Comment: I should emphasis this is not specific to autotools. I'm after a good common ground for where to put these things.

Comment: This question is getting lots of love but not many loved answers :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the macros affect system headers, they probably ought to go somewhere where they affect every source file that includes those system headers (which includes those that include them indirectly). The most logical place would therefore be on the command line, assuming your build system allows you to set e.g. CPPFLAGS to affect the compilation of every file.

If you use precompiled headers, and have a precompiled header that must therefore be included first in every source file (e.g. stdafx.h for MSVC projects) then you could put them in there too.

For macros that affect self-contained libraries (whether third-party or written by you), I would create a wrapper header that defines the macros and then includes the library header. All uses of the library from your project should then include your wrapper header rather than including the library header directly. This avoids defining macros unnecessarily, and makes it clear that they relate to that library. If there are dependencies between libraries then you might want to make the macros global (in the build system or precompiled header) just to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it depends.

Most, I'd define via the command line - in a Makefile or whatever build system you use.

As for `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS` I really wouldn't define it explicitly, but rather use `getconf LFS_CFLAGS` and `getconf LFS_LDFLAGS`.

Comment: A nice tip with the LFS stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I would always put them on the command line via `CPPFLAGS` for the whole project. If you put them any other place, there's a danger that you might forget to copy them into a new source file or include a system header before including the project header that defines them, and this could lead to extremely nasty bugs (like one file declaring a legacy 32-bit `struct stat` and passing its address to a function in another file which expects a 64-bit `struct stat`).

BTW, it's really ridiculous that `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` still isn't the default on glibc.

Comment: It certainly is _insane_. I'm guessing this is a vote for entire source repo via the compiler.

Comment: When using automake, it is better to put the flags in AM_CPPFLAGS.  The maintainer should never set CPPFLAGS directly, but allow the user to set it at configure time.

Comment: This is probably not the place for my "automake considered harmful" rant... ;-)

Comment: Is that similar to the "Recursive make Considered Harmful" paper?

Comment: @R.., by all means, please rant, or link to a rant. The more ammunition I have against using it, the better.

Answer (score 1):

Most projects that I've seen use them did it via `-D` command line options.  They are there because that eases building the source with different compilers and system headers.  If you were to build with a system compiler for another system that didn't need them or needed a different set of them then a configure script can easily change the command line arguments that a make file passes to the compiler.

It's probably best to do it for the entire program because some of the flags effect which version of a function gets brought in or the size/layout of a struct and mixing those up could cause crazy things if you aren't careful.

They certainly are annoying to keep up with.

Comment: Yeah I run into the "different definitions" issue very often, and it causes all kinds of confusion.

Answer (score 1):

For `_GNU_SOURCE` and the autotools in particular, you could use `AC_USE_SYSTEM_EXTENSIONS` (citing liberally from the autoconf manual here):

> -- Macro: `AC_USE_SYSTEM_EXTENSIONS`
>       This macro was introduced in Autoconf 2.60.  If possible, enable
>       extensions to C or Posix on hosts that normally disable the
>       extensions, typically due to standards-conformance namespace
>       issues.  This should be called before any macros that run the C
>       compiler.  The following preprocessor macros are defined where
>       appropriate:
>
> `_GNU_SOURCE`
>            Enable extensions on GNU/Linux.
>
> `__EXTENSIONS__`
>            Enable general extensions on Solaris.
>
> `_POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS`
>            Enable threading extensions on Solaris.
>
> `_TANDEM_SOURCE`
>            Enable extensions for the HP NonStop platform.
>
> `_ALL_SOURCE`
>            Enable extensions for AIX 3, and for Interix.
>
> `_POSIX_SOURCE`
>            Enable Posix functions for Minix.
>
> `_POSIX_1_SOURCE`
>            Enable additional Posix functions for Minix.
>
> `_MINIX`
>            Identify Minix platform.  This particular preprocessor macro
>            is obsolescent, and may be removed in a future release of
>            Autoconf.

For `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS`, you need to call `AC_SYS_LARGEFILE` and `AC_FUNC_FSEEKO`:

> — Macro: `AC_SYS_LARGEFILE`
>
> Arrange for 64-bit file offsets, known as large-file support. On some hosts, one must use special compiler options to build programs that can access large files. Append any such options to the output variable `CC`. Define `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS` and `_LARGE_FILES` if necessary.
>
> Large-file support can be disabled by configuring with the `--disable-largefile` option.
>
> If you use this macro, check that your program works even when `off_t` is wider than `long int`, since this is common when large-file support is enabled. For example, it is not correct to print an arbitrary `off_t` value `X` with `printf("%ld", (long int) X)`.
>
> The LFS introduced the `fseeko` and `ftello` functions to replace their C counterparts `fseek` and `ftell` that do not use `off_t`. Take care to use `AC_FUNC_FSEEKO` to make their prototypes available when using them and large-file support is enabled.

If you are using `autoheader` to generate a `config.h`, you could define the other macros you care about using `AC_DEFINE` or `AC_DEFINE_UNQUOTED`:

```
AC_DEFINE([FUSE_VERSION], [28], [FUSE Version.])
```

The definition will then get passed to the command line or placed in `config.h`, if you're using autoheader. The real benefit of `AC_DEFINE` is that it easily allows preprocessor definitions as a result of configure checks and separates system-specific cruft from the important details.

When writing the `.c` file, `#include "config.h"` first, then the interface header (e.g., `foo.h` for `foo.c` - this ensures that the header has no missing dependencies), then all other headers.

Answer (score 0):

I usually put them as close as practicable to the things that need them, whilst ensuring you don't set them incorrectly.

Related pieces of information *should* be kept close to make it easier to identify. A classic example is the ability for C to now allow variable definitions anywhere in the code rather than just at the top of a function:

```
void something (void) {
    // 600 lines of code here
    int x = fn(y);
    // more code here
}
```

is a lot better than:

```
void something (void) {
    int x;
    // 600 lines of code here
    x = fn(y);
    // more code here
}
```

since you don't have to go searching for the type of `x` in the latter case.

---

By way of example, if you need to compile a single source file multiple times with different values, you *have* to do it with the compiler:

```
gcc -Dmydefine=7 -o binary7 source.c
gcc -Dmydefine=9 -o binary9 source.c
```

However, if every compilation of that file will use 7, it can be moved closer to the place where it's used:

```
source.c:
    #include <stdio.h>

    #define mydefine 7
    #include "header_that_uses_mydefine.h"

    #define mydefine 7
    #include "another_header_that_uses_mydefine.h"
```

Note that I've done it twice so that it's more localised. This isn't a problem since, if you change only one, the compiler will tell you about it, but it ensures that you know those defines are set for the specific headers.

---

And, if you're certain that you will *never* include (for example) `bitio.h` without first setting `BITCOUNT` to 8, you can even go so far as to create a `bitio8.h` file containing nothing but:

```
#define BITCOUNT 8
#include "bitio.h"
```

and then just include `bitio8.h` in your source files.

Answer (score 0):

Using header files is what I recommend because it allows you to have a code base built by make files and other build systems as well as IDE projects such as Visual Studio. This gives you a single point of definition that can be accompanied by comments (I'm a fan of [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) which allows you to generate [macro documentation](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmddef)).

The other benefit with header files is that you can easily write unit tests to verify that only valid combinations of macros are defined.

Answer (score 0):

Global, project-wide constants that are target specific are best put in CCFLAGS in your makefile. Constants you use all over the place can go in appropriate header files which are included by any file that uses them.

For example,

```
// bool.h - a boolean type for C
#ifndef __BOOL_H__
#define BOOL_H
typedef int bool_t
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
#endif
```

Then, in some other header,

```
`#include "bool.h"`
// blah
```