# Program needs CFLAGS=-D_GNU_SOURCE added to compile, where should this go?

Tags: c, autotools

I have a project that uses autotools. I want to add -D_GNU_SOURCE when I compile the project. I could just hack this into the Makefile or configure script, but they get overwritten by configure.am and Makefile.am when I generate new ones before release.

Where is the right place to define this and what is the correct syntax, is there a macro I should be using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Macro definitions for headers, where to put them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384741/macro-definitions-for-headers-where-to-put-them)

Comment: I think this is different. I am asking what the best practice is for defining these types of options when building a project using autotools. That other question is about what to do when using any build system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can can modify `CFLAGS` by adding a line like this to your `configure.ac` file:

```
CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -D_GNU_SOURCE"
```

then regenerate your configure script (this adds to the existing `CFLAGS` rather than replacing it, which it what you should do - so users can specify their own `CFLAGS` options when compiling and your script won't overwrite them).

However, for the specific case of `_GNU_SOURCE`, you should instead use the builtin autoconf macro:

```
AC_GNU_SOURCE
```

Place this early in your `configure.ac` file, before any rules that invoke the C compiler.  Note that this doesn't add `-D_GNU_SOURCE` to `CFLAGS`, though - if you're using a configuration header (set with `AC_CONFIG_HEADER`) then it adds a definition for `_GNU_SOURCE` to that, and if you're not then it adds `-D_GNU_SOURCE=1` to `DEFS`, which you can add to `CFLAGS` in your Makefile.

If you're using a configuration header (which for any non-trivial autoconf project, you probably should be) then it should be included before any system headers.

Comment: I added that macro to configure.ac and reran autoconf, make fails after running configure.

Comment: @effervescent-phantom: `AC_GNU_SOURCE` adds the definition either to `DEFS` or to your configuration header if you're using one.  In the former case you need to ensure that the definitions in `DEFS` are passed to the compiler, in the latter case you need to ensure your configuration header is included in your source files prior to the system headers.